# Change paypal next payment date in existing and executed billing agreement?

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I used PayPal SDK to create and execute a billing agreement that was supposed to charge the client every 3 months.

However, I used the `setup_fee` to charge the customer immediately and set the start date to be 1 month in the future instead of 3.

I can see on the customer's profile that the customer next payment due date is in one month and I am not capable of changing the next payment date.

I've already tried using the billing agreement update method, but it doesn't let me change the `start_date` or `next_payment_date`.

**Any idea how I can change the next payment date for the existing billing agreement that have already been executed?**

Answer (score 4):

### The answer is not great, but the somewhat solution I found was to *suspend the plans*.

---

#### To give more context, my problem was the following:

- User subscribed to quarterly paid plan **on September 15th** and paid `setup_fee`
- Next payment was incorrectly configured to be on **October 15th** - because I added a month to the start date*
- The actual next payment date should be 3 months after, on **December 15h**

#### My "solution":

1. I paused the subscriptions for those users **before October 15th**, more specifically **on October 10th**.
2. I restarted the solution 2 days after the incorrect `next_payment_date`, **on October 17th**.
3. Once the plan was restarted the `next_payment_date` was set to 3 months later, so it was set to **January 15th**.

So as you can observe, I was not able to actually fix it, but rather I accepted to "lose" a month.

*Note: Paypal support was LESS than useful. At first their recommendation was to cancel the plan and ask the users to buy again. Then I sugggested the approach of suspending and they INCORRECTLY confirmed to me that the next payment date would be the correct one, and that was not true, **it was ONE month later**. So be aware of what their support says.*